# Using MySQLi inside function with Slim 3

Tags: php, mysqli, dependency-injection, slim-3

I am new to Slim and I need help making mysqli available inside function that I use inside one of my routes.

Now I use mysqli this way (and I know that this is not the right way) - it is someRoute.php file

```
$app->post('/api/someRoute', function($request, $response) {
    require_once('dbconnect.php');

    $mysqli->query("SELECT ......");
    someFunc();
}

function someFunc() {
    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE ......");
}
```

Function called someFunc is not working because it can't access mysqli.
What is the best way to make MySQLi available in any part of code?

**Update:**
Following examples I found this way, but I don't understand how to use in inside functions like someFunc

```
$container['mysqli'] = function ($c) {
   ......
    $mysqli  = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
    return $mysqli;
};
```

Comment: why this question is tagged with dependency-injection?

Comment: I found that it was mentioned many times discussing db connection in slim and other frameworks

Comment: and so, why not to use it?

Comment: I will be glad if you can provide example that can be used with functions. I found this example https://arjunphp.com/creating-restful-api-slim-framework/ but I don't understand how to use db connection inside my functions (not routes)

Comment: make it a function parameter

Comment: I am already came to this solution. It is not looking pretty for me. How can i set mysqli to be global variable?

Comment: it is setting mysqli to be global variable would be "not pretty" to say the least. better get rid of functions and use classes/methods instead.

Comment: What i want is to see some answers about how to handle my question. If you don't want to post answer maybe someone else would.